# Java error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.  I have Dbvis (DbVisualizer - database editortu) installed, but now it will not work.  I get the following when I run `dbvis` from the command-line:

```
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:807)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:886)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1736)
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1294)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingUtilities.java:1295)
at com.onseven.dbvis.DbVisualizerGUI.main(Z:594)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)

:~$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, mixed mode)

:~$ javac -version
javac 10.0.2
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
Thanks for any help.